# Is there any External Direct Product which is cyclic but it is the product of two non-cyclic groups?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups, direct-product

Is there any External Direct Product which is cyclic but it is the product of two non-cyclic groups?

I know that for an EDP, say $G\times G'$ to be cyclic the $\gcd(o(G),o(G'))=1$.

But I am unable to find any EDP for the above problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will not be able to find such an example: every subgroup of a cyclic group is again cyclic. So the factors of the external direct product must be cyclic.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $H,K$ are not cyclic but $G=H\times K$ is. Then

$$H'=\{(h,e_K)\mid h\in H\}$$

is a noncyclic subgroup of $G$. But every subgroup of a cyclic group is itself cyclic!

Some Theorems you need:

- If $G_1,G_2$ are groups such that $G_1\cong G_2$ and $G_1$ is cyclic, then $G_2$ is cyclic. (Use the contrapositive of this.)
- Subgroups of a group are themselves groups.
- Here $H'\cong H$.